# Возможно ли восстановление файлов на линуксовых файловых системах?

Tags: linux, файлы, файловая-система, восстановление, ext4

На ntfs удалённый файл довольно легко восстановить и для этого есть куча программ.

А возможно ли такое же восстановление в linux для файловых систем ext*?

Comment: Да у меня там было порядка 300 гигов инфы) Или вы всё-таки очень хотите помочь мне? Или это вообще не про меня?

Comment: @misdeed, да мне уже просто интересно стало.

Comment: https://losst.ru/vosstanovlenie-udalennyh-fajlov-linux

Comment: Щас запустил ```foremost -i /dev/sda2 -t pdf -o ~/Restore``` - отпишусь о результатах.

Comment: R-Studio обещает восстанавливать файлы и под Linux (Но сам я не пробовал использовать её с extfs. Под windows - это одна из лучших программ восстановления). https://www.r-studio.com/ru/data_recovery_linux .  Программа немножко коммерческая, но в вопросе вроде ничего про свободность не говорилось.

Comment: @Qwertiy команда выше не справилась с задачей. Точнее, я её остановил до того, как она, теоретически могла бы справиться...) 2 часа работает, а толку нет

Comment: Тока хотел написать про testdisk, но выше уже дали ссылку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если кратко, то нормального способа принципиально нет. Далее идёт не столько описание того, как восстановить файлы, а скорее почему это так сложно на ext3+ и обзор альтернатив.

## ext2

Для ext2 есть полноценный undelete с несколькими реализациями. Например, в составе [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)'а. Работает примерно по тем же принципам, что и для fat/ntfs. Т.е. ищет в каталогах записи об удалённых файлах, находит иноды на которые они ссылались и по ним данные.

## ext3/ext4

С появлением ext3 начались проблемы. И самое обидное, что дело не в том, что изменилась структура ФС, а в том, что при удалении файла блок указателей в его иноде зануляется (вместо того чтобы просто помечать инод как не используемый). Как <s>объясняет</s> [оправдывается](http://batleth.sapienti-sat.org/projects/FAQs/ext3-faq.html) один из разработчиков, это сделано, чтобы повысить отказоустойчивость в случае сбоя; но так или иначе это просто убило все старые утилиты для ext2, а также принципиальную возможность создания нормального undelete'а, оставив только извращённые способы.

#### Выпиливание файлов (file carving)

Утилиты использующие эту методику ищут на жёстком диске определённые сигнатуры и пытаются собрать вокруг них файлы. Примеры: [photorec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec), [foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/).

Достоинства:

- Есть вероятность восстановить файл как бы сильно ни была повреждена ФС.

Недостатки:

- Ненадёжный способ.
- Крайне затратен по времени.
- Невозможно восстановить имя файла (и то в каком каталоге он находился).
- Невозможно восстановить файл произвольной структуры

#### Восстановление основываясь на записях в журнале

Относительно новая [идея](https://carlowood.github.io/howto/undelete_ext3.html)([перевод](http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/file-sys/undel_ext3_1.html)). Подтвердившая возможность в ext3grep и развитая в [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/) и [ext4magick](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext4magic/).

Достоинства:

- Гипотетически есть возможность восстановить файл даже если его inode оказался перезаписан.

Недостатки:

- Способ менее надёжный, нежели классический.
- Максимальное количество восстанавливаемых файлов ограничено размером журнала.

### Полезное чтение:

- [Why Recovering a Deleted Ext3 File Is Difficult...](https://web.archive.org/web/20181222094352/http://linux.sys-con.com/node/117909/)
- [Структура ext4.](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout)

Comment: Вчера [такой же вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1409173/232). Нашел к нему вот [такое исследование](https://elar.urfu.ru/bitstream/10995/65660/1/978-5-7996-2404-0_2018-90.pdf) восстановления по журналу.

Comment: @avp, это то же самое, что делает `ext3grep` и последователи...

Comment: Да, я уже понял, что студент читал те же ссылки