# Создание утилиты по восстановлению удаленных файлов в ext2/ext3/ext4

Tags: c

Базовое понимание о файловой системе имеется, но, видимо, недостаточное. В интернете я нашел некоторые источники, но там все написано сложным языком. Поэтому хотелось бы узнать принцип действия и хоть какую-нибудь реализацию у знающих на понятном языке. Заранее спасибо за любое содействие.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Говорят, ext очень проблемный в плане восстановления файлов

Comment: Вот [это](https://elar.urfu.ru/bitstream/10995/65660/1/978-5-7996-2404-0_2018-90.pdf) читали?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Возможно ли восстановление файлов на линуксовых файловых системах?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843742/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%85)